# div background image crossfade using timer

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I have a div with background images that fade. I want to cross fade them however I am only able to fade them to white, then back to the next image. I tried using fadeTo() instead of fadeIn() however there was not much difference. Here's the code:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
      var b_imgs = ["dl1.jpg", "dl2.jpeg"];
      $(function () {
          var i = 0;
          $("#index_jum").css("background-image", "url(/assets/" + b_imgs[i] + ")");
          setInterval(function () {
              i++;
              if (i == b_imgs.length) {
                  i = 0;
              }
              $("#index_jum").fadeOut(2500, function () {
                  $(this).css("background-image", "url(/assets/" + b_imgs[i] + ")");
                  $(this).fadeIn(2500);
              });
          }, 9000);
      });
</script>
```

The HTML:

```
<section id="index_jum" class="mouse-bg row" data-autoheight="true">
```

The CSS:

```
    #index_jum{
 background-size: cover;
     -webkit-background-size: cover;
     -moz-background-size: cover;
     -o-background-size: cover;
}
```

How do I crossfade the images? Or is there a way to fadeIn()/fadeOut() to black instead of white? Currently the images fade in and fade out however there is a white transition. ie. image1 fade to white, white fade to image2

Comment: Please provide your HTML aswell. And note that your images are local so would be neat to have them too.

Comment: You aren't fading to white. The background colour of the element that sits behind `#index_jum` is showing through.